# Updating a field values based off of values in the same column

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, cursor

I am struggling with the concept of this code and am not sure if this is even something I can do.

I am using a gdb with a feature dataset and a number of feature classes. I have a feature class "TransportationGroundCrv" and within it is a field FCSUBTYPE. This distinguishes which type of transportation the line feature will represent (road, bridge, railway etc.) The bridges or in line with a road segment, and it's important that the bridge is wider (depicted through the WID field) than the road it is coincident with.

Because they are within the field of the same table, I am having a hard time figuring out how to automate the task of comparing the WID of the Road value to the WID of the Bridge value in order to make the bridge wider than the road.

[image]

So far I have selected the bridges which are coincident with the roads

```
roadSelect = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('TransportationGroundCrv', 'NEW_SELECTION', "'F_CODE'='ROAD'")

bridgeSelect = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('TransportationGroundCrv', 'NEW_SELECTION', "'F_CODE'='BRIDGE'")

brSelect = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(roadSelect, 'CONTAINS_CLEMENTINI', bridgeSelect, "", 'SUBSET_SELECTION')
```

Next thing is I want to figure out how to iterate through the rows from the selection of brSelect.

I'm thinking an updateCursor

```
updateFields = ['FCSUBTYPE', 'WID']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(brSelect, updateFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
```

But I'm getting stuck here because I don't know how to differentiate between the WID field for the bridge and the WID field associated with the road in order to compare their width. I think maybe some sort of SQL beforehand is in order but I am not as familiar with it.

Comment: Do you have some sort of unique id that associates the bridges with the roads? If not, that might be the place to start. Give road segments their own ID, then use a spatial join or something along those lines to assign the road to the bridge they touch.